# Enterprise Architect DDL generation order

Tags: code-generation, enterprise-architect

I currently work on a pretty large project with a pretty large database. Logically, there are many constraint requirements, so when I want to generate DDL from the EA script, I get the generations in a wrong order, leading to errors. 
I have the tables separated to folders by modules and I have the modules and the tables inside those folders sorted by required order like:

```
MODULE 1
|_ Table 1
|_ Table 2
MODULE 2
|_ Table 3
|_ Table 4
```

but when I try to generate DDL, I get those all messed up. Like

```
Table 2
Table 4
Table 3
Table 1
```

But with the exception that there are 66 of these so manually sorting them using DDL Generation GUI would be a real pain.

In addition, this sorted order does not seem to follow any intuitive sorting criteria. The list is not sorted by name, it is not sorted by modules (folders), it is not even sorted by time of creation, as some of the newest tables are sitting comfortably in the middle. The only pattern I found is that sequences are generated first, but they are not even a real concern to me.

Is there any way to avoid manually sorting the generated order and go with the Project Browser order automatically (without the workaround being even more complicated like writing my own parser)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I often had to export EA models in various formats (not only DDL). I dropped that awkward Sparx scripting "language" a long time ago and used the API to create any export files instead. That not only gives a greater flexibility in controlling the output, it also helps avoiding to ask for workarounds like this one ;-)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, but I am unable to go with that solution, because my whole team is used to generate DDLs via EA.

Comment: That solution will still use EA, but instead of the awkward scripting you'd use the more standard scripting. EA supports VB and J(ava)Script in-build and any external (add-in) way via the API. And most likely there's no remedy for that obscure behavior if you stay with the awkward DDL script provided by EA except you send a feature request. Prepare to hold your breath for a loooong time then.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Options' part of the Generate DDL, there's a an option to 'Separate Constraints from Tables'.  Setting that to True adds the table constraints after all tables have been created, getting around the issue.